# How do I set anchors for the postman documentation?

Tags: postman

I make the documentation for api, how to make a cross reference (named anchor) with markdown in postman?

Is there such a similar option?

```
Take me to <a href="#api"> rest api </a> ... <a name="api"> this is rest api </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an element with an id "api" in a collection/folder/request description, and then link it in another place like `[rest api](#api)`

If you want to link a folder or request, you should get the ID (from the documentation itself) and then using the same Markdown as before with the respective ID.

**Note:** Take into account that Postman Documentation doesn't provide (at this moment) a way to specify a custom ID for a folder or request, so in case you're trying to do that, the best you can do is create an element with an id at the top of the description and then linking to that new element. It will scroll to a point *under* the title, which may result in a poorer user experience.